# UIScrollView+setContentOffset+AutoLayout

Tags: ios6, ios4, xcode4.5, autolayout

Some `UITextField`s and `UIButton`s are subviews of a `UIScrollView`. I set autolayout property. All working fine except I had the problem when I click on  a textfield to type. I gave `setContentOffset`-property to **visible** in my textfield. This also worked, but when I type something in textfield `contentOffset` is gone. Means my textfield is invisible and goes behind keyboard.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the pictures you have in the post are showing?

Comment: I don't have sufficient reputations to post pictures in question.